# FileListBox no muestra archivos con extensiones ocultas en explorador de Windows

Tags: vb6

Tengo un problema con la opción "Ocultar extensiones de archivos conocidas" en el explorador de Windows y Visual Basic 6, en concreto con el componente FileListBox.

El problema me ha ocurrido al instalar en un par de clientes un programa que, entre otras cosas, muestra archivos *.mp3 de un directorio a través de un FileListBox. El caso es que me aparecía vacío el listado de archivos, cuando realmente sí había archivos mp3 en el directorio correspondiente.

Para que apareciesen tuve que cerrar el programa y desmarcar el check de "Ocultar extensiones de archivos conocidas" en su configuración del explorador de Windows, cosa que no me hace ninguna gracia tener que hacer. En ambos casos era un Windows 7.

He intentado reproducir el caso en mi ordenador, también con Windows 7, en Windows 10 y Windows XP pero aunque tenga activado el check de "Ocultar extensiones de archivos conocidas" en mi caso sí me salen, con lo cual también me veo un poco limitado a la hora de corregir este comportamiento.

¿Qué explicación puede tener todo esto? ¿Como me puedo asegurar para futuras instalaciones que me muestre los archivos en FileListBox aunque el cliente tenga activado el check de "Ocultar extensiones de archivos conocidas"?

Comment: Necesitariamos alguna forma de reproducir el problema.. si no, estamos igual que vos...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @gbianchi, ese también es mi problema, que no consigo reproducir el comportamiento en mis ordenadores.